# Update data through checkbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I can't get this to work. I need to update the value of a column of the checked checkboxes in mysql. When I click the button it is supposed to update the value of the checked checkboxes. Here is my code for **editLayout.php**:

```
<form action="updateLayout.php" method="POST">
<input name="update" type="SUBMIT" value="Update" id="update">
<?php       
$x = 'seats';

$linkID = @ mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Newpass123#") or die("Could not connect to MySQL server");
@ mysql_select_db("seatmapping") or die("Could not select database");

/* Create and execute query. */
$query = "SELECT * from $x order by rowId, columnId desc";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$prevRowId = null;
$seatColor = null;
$tableRow = false;

//echo $result;
echo "<table class='map'>";
while (list($rowId, $columnId, $status, $name, $seatid) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
if ($prevRowId != $rowId) {
    if ($rowId != 'A') {
        echo "</tr></table></td>";
        echo "\n</tr>";
    }
    $prevRowId = $rowId;
    echo "\n<tr><td align='center'><table><tr>";
} else {
    $tableRow = false;
}
if ($status == 0) {
    $seatColor = "#A6E22E";
} 
else if ($status == 1){
    $seatColor = "#D34836";
}
else if ($status == 2){
    $seatColor = "#00A0D1";
}

echo "\n<td bgcolor='$seatColor'>";
echo $seatid;
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='seats[]' id='seats' value=".$seatid.">  </checkbox>";
echo "</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";

/* Close connection to database server. */
mysql_close();
?>
```

And here is my code for the jquery residing on different page (**functions.js**). I already included this in the header:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$("form input[id='update']").click(function() {

    var count_checked = $("[name='seats[]']:checked").length;
    if(count_checked == 0) {
        alert("Please select product(s) to update.");
        return false;
    }
    if(count_checked == 1) {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to update these product?");
    } else {
        return confirm("Are you sure you want to update these products?");
      }
});
});
```

And here is my **updateLayout.php**.:

```
 <?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Newpass123#");
if(!$db) { echo mysql_error(); }
$select_db = mysql_select_db("seatmapping");
if(!$select_db) { echo mysql_error(); }

if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
$id_array = $_POST['seats'];
$id_count = count($_POST['seats']);

for($i=0; $i < $id_count; $i++) {
    $id = $id_array[$i];
    $query = mysql_query("Update `seats` set `status`='2' where  `seatid`='$seatid'");
    if(!$query) { die(mysql_error()); }
}
header("Location: editLayout.php");
}
?>
```

I'm using **jquery 1.11.0**. I know there's a lot of sql injection in here and im still using mysql but I plan to change it all once I get this to work. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what it is exactly that's not working.

Comment: -1 for using `@` for functions there.

Comment: The value of the checked checkboxes is supposed to change the value of $status=2 when i click the Submit Button. And the form is submited to the **updateLayout.php**. Sorry for lack of info. Im a newbie in php programming..

Comment: remove the location header in updateLayout.php, so you can see if there are any errors during the update. Print out the mysql query to check whether the query is correct...

Comment: @ReinderWit i've tried what youve said. I removed the location header. and printed out **$status**. there was no changes made they are still 1's and 0's. they should be equal to 2 after the update, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your update query doesn't use the correct update value. You use '$seatid', which isn't declared anywhere. You should use '$id'.

Change

```
for($i=0; $i < $id_count; $i++) {
    $id = $id_array[$i];
    $query = mysql_query("Update `seats` set `status`='2' where  `seatid`='$seatid'");
    if(!$query) { die(mysql_error()); }
}
```

into

```
for($i=0; $i < $id_count; $i++) {
    $id = $id_array[$i];
    $query = mysql_query("Update `seats` set `status`='2' where  `seatid`='$id'");
    if(!$query) { die(mysql_error()); }
}
```

Comment: Wow! You're a genius it worked. How could i have not noticed that. Im such a newbie haha. I wish i could upvote your answer but i need 15 reputation.. THANKS!